# Can't target WSL from VS 2017 - Error Could not find 'zip' archiver

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was attempting to setup VS 2017 15.7.6 to compile a console app I have for Linux.  Then I was going to attempt to target WSL.
Following this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/

I get to the Connect Remote System step and add enter in the information, choose Connect and get:

Error Dialog "Downloading and updating headers for Intellisense" pops up with the text "An error has occurred. Could not find the 'zip' archiver, please install it using your system package manager..."

I'm assuming I need to issue an apt-get command from my WSL prompt.  But I'm not sure which one.

Anyone else run into this?
I'm very new to WSL and Linux.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I can no connect anyway and I am able to hit a breakpoint running my console application.  In the Linux console window, I do see the text immediately before any text from my application:  &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"

Comment: I found another help page where I was apparently supposed to run sudo apt install zip.  I figured it'd be something simple.

Comment: @Biswapriyo - I'm now able to connect and debug.  I had simply needed to install the zip package.